# Are DateTimes passed by reference in C#? If not, why is my object updating as I change a variable?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have ran into a problem which I simply cannot get my head around. When I debug the program, I can see the program works fine - this is the strange part.

The issue I am facing is when I append to a List with the new object - it seems to completely change. Let me explain better by showing my code.

```
        System.DateTime timeNow = System.DateTime.Now;

        List<Train> trainsOnNet = new List<Train>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Train t = new Train();

            t.NewCarrige(true, "A"[0]);
            t.NewCarrige(false, "B"[0]);

            t.addStation(App.Stations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetShortCode().Equals("MTG")));
            t.addStation(App.Stations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetShortCode().Equals("BNS")));
            t.addStation(App.Stations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetShortCode().Equals("BSH")));

            int minsToAdd = 5;

            t.GetStations().ForEach(x =>
            {
                timeNow = timeNow.AddMinutes(minsToAdd);
                x.SetArrivalTime(timeNow);
                minsToAdd += 10;
            });

            timeNow = timeNow.AddMinutes(15);

            trainsOnNet.Add(t);

        }
```

When I add `t` to the `trainsOnNet` List, the time seems to change to the last time that the loop will generate, even before it generates.

If I place a stopper on this line, I can see that the `t` instance has the correct time variables (ie, 5 minutes from the current execution time and then 10 minutes between each). However, when I then press continue and inspect the `trainsOnNet` list. This time has been changed to the next trains set of times.

It appears to me that `timeNow` is being passed by reference, and as the loop increases the time, the stored time updates until I am left with 3 trains all saying the same time.

For example, if I execute the program at 1951 with a stopper on `trainsOnNet.Add(t)` I can see that `t` holds 3 stations, in which the first stations Arrival time is 19:56 and the second is 20:11 and 20:26. Perfect. I then hit continue and inspect the newly appended object to my list. On inspection, the `t` instance arrival time properties have now changed to:

20:56, 21:11, 21:36

Doing the maths of my code, the next train should arrive 20 minutes after the previous train has arrived at the end station. Which brings me to 20:46. Thus deeming it more confusing why the first train is being changed past the second trains expected time let alone being updated without stating to do so.

Any ideas would be greatly appricated.

Stop on the line on the first execution:
[image]

Stop on same line, after pressing continue (changed properties):
[image]

As you can see, the values are being changed? In this case, by a whole hour?

Comment: to partially clear out the doubts: `System.DateTime` is a "value type" (so, no, it's not passed by reference). You can check that by seeing on your intellisense in Visual Studio or in the documentation that it is declared as a `struct`, not a `class` (the latter are reference types).

Comment: I did clarify this before hand, because it was the only thing that made sense to me at the time to what could of been causing this. But, as stated, I had doubts that this could be the problem but clearly there is something I am not seeing @Pac0

Comment: it is because timenow is outer variable and so it's incremented in each enumeration

Comment: Can you show x.SetArrivalTime.

Comment: `public void SetArrivalTime(System.DateTime arrivalTime) { ArrivalTime = arrivalTime; }` @AliAhmad

Comment: DateTime is a struct : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b,references

Comment: @Jaquarh, you need to make tempTimeNow = timeNow and use it in a loop

Comment: How would I approach doing this? Put the `tempTimeNow` at the top and add the minutes to this new variable or at the bottom after I've updated the `timeNow` variable? @sTrenat

Comment: You can clone when assign to Arrivaltime.

Comment: first option, at the begining of each enumeration

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this now @sTrenat

Comment: Your screenshots are not really explicit. If you want to debug the problem you suspect, you should really inspect the value of the corresponding object after one line execution, not a full iteration. There are a lot of things going on in the code.

Comment: I think you didn't precise what is an expected result. 
Should each next train start 15 min later then previous?

Comment: Apologies, C# isn't my strongest language - I prefer Java. Perhaps I could upload the project to GitHub if this helps you understand it better? @Pac0

Comment: The last comment was to convey that, if you have something you feel is very strange / don't understand, you should prefer line-by-line debugging to "demonstrate" (to you or to any one else) the precise behavior. This advice applies whether you use C# or Java, or another procedural / oop language

Comment: to be  more precise, you should set up a break point in all the lines of the 'for each' and the line after as well.

Comment: what we still do not know: what is `App.Stations`, what does `t.addStation()` do, and which class holds the property `ArrivalTime`?

Comment: No this makes sense, I did not expect the issue to be related to how and where I store the Station and get the Station from. This is 100% an issue deeper into the program and not related to the actual TimeDate logic I am using. I can debug and fix this issue myself now, however, I will make this the correct answer due to it guiding the fact that the issue is within the Station. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.DateTime` is a "value type". You can check that by seeing on your intellisense in Visual Studio or in the documentation that it is declared as a `struct`, not a `class` (the latter are reference types).

Your problem, however, is not really about this.

It's not clear what you exactly intend to do, and the flaw is probbaly in your logic implementation.

1 -  you **reuse** the same variable `timeNow` for all iterations, it's hard (at least to me) to keep track on how much it is supposed to be and how much the value is after a few "mental" iterations.

2 - you set `minsToAdd` to 5, then increase it by 10 in loop. So, after a few iterations of the inner loop, `minsToAdd` gets these values :
15, 25, 35, 45, etc...

Then, you add this to `timeNow`, so imagine that `timeNow` is 00:00 at the beginning, in the inner loop it gets values

```
00:05,
00:05 + 15min = 00:20
00:20 + 25min = 00:55
00:55 + 35min = 01:30
etc...
```

and after the inner loop you add 15 min to the last value.

**Is that what you expect?**

Comment: My expected output is, 5 minutes from the execution time should be the first stations arrival time. Every station in between should be 10 minutes apart. Every train should reach the first station then after 15 minutes of the previous train arriving at the final destination. I hope this cleared anything up? Currently, this works fine and the formula lacks no logic issues, only, for some reason, at the end of this `for` loop, I am left with 3 trains all with the same times.

Comment: @sTrenat see the above comment for expected output

Comment: @Jaquarh, above description isn't obvious for me, I guess this is what you expect but I'm still not sure if i understand your description: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z6qIxY

Comment: ah! as you described it last,  then the maybe the only thing to do is to _set_ `minstoadd =  10` in the `.ForEach`, not, increase it by 10 at each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your exact fiddle and it still leaves me with 3 trains at the same times @sTrenat

Comment: @Jaquarh ähm, that's probably because you save the times on the stations so they are likely to getting overwritten every loop, so at the end, you only have the times of the last train

Comment: @PatrickBeynio - I can absolutely see this now, the Stations are what hold the times and since all 3 trains use the same Station, it reads only the last stored time. Perhaps I need to create a copy of the Station and add it to the train rather than using the same Station for all! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these two lines:

```
timeNow = timeNow.AddMinutes(minsToAdd);
x.SetArrivalTime(timeNow);
```

To just:

```
x.SetArrivalTime(timeNow.AddMinutes(minsToAdd));
```

As others explained, you're overriding the `timeNow` variable with each iteration. This change should give you the expected result.

Comment: This, again, leaves me with 3 trains all at the same time, weirdly enough. I found that `timeNow.AddMinutes(minsToAdd)` due to variables not being immutable in C# has to be re-declared to update (hence the `timeNow = timeNow.AddMinutes()`)